Private EKS with only Ingress exposed
On my team, we are trying to create an EKS cluster, which is created in 2 subnets, lets say in us-east-1a and us-east-1d, which are routeable subnets. And we plan to create the nodegroup and nodes in us-east-1b and us-east-1c which are PRIVATE subnets, which are no routeables.
When doing this, we are having an issue beacuse, nodes get created but fail to join the cluster, which lets the cluster provisioned, the node group created, the instances created and booted up, but they fail to join the cluster.
Is this actually achivable?
What are we doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.
